# creating a firemonkey component

Tags: delphi, components, firemonkey, delphi-xe4

I'm working with Firemonkey in Delphi XE4 and I'm unable to create a new component using the menu item Component -> New Component.
Whether the component is a VCL or Firemonkey component or whether I create a package first the result is the same.
The Tool Palette in Delphi appears to be searched and gradually it closes leaving it empty of components and a component dialog box that says "No Items available" when it comes to selecting an ancestor component.

I have two separate installations of Delphi XE4 and the same symptoms appear on both.
It appears that Delphi believes that there are no suitable base components on which to build a new component.

Answer (score 3):

Creating components is fairly straightforward in code.

- Create a unit.
- Add code for your component.
- Add a Register procedure.

  ```
  procedure Register;
  begin
    RegisterComponents('NewPage', [TMyComponent]);
  end;
  ```
- Add a declaration for Register in the implements section.
- Add a call to RegisterFMXClasses in your initialization section.

  ```
  implementation
  uses FMX.Types;
  ...
  initialization
    RegisterFMXClasses([TMyComponent]);
  end.
  ```
- Create a package.
- Add the unit to the package.
- Right-click the package (in the top-right panel) and select Install.

(Note: It's usually best to create your component at run time whilst testing. You only need to do the package stuff once it's fairly stable).

Comment: Although this is generally true, it does not answer the question why the standard delphi way via Component - New Component does not work.