# Create a composite firemonkey control in Delphi 10 Seattle

Tags: delphi, controls, firemonkey, delphi-10-seattle

I want to create a composite control in FireMonkey following this [example](http://blog.delphiedintorni.it/2013/11/tgmaillabel-un-esempio-di-custom.html), where the control style is read from a resource file. This example works well when install the component with Delphi XE6, but when I install in Delphi 10 Seattle generates an acces violation error when load the form,  and I can not figure out where the problem is. The error raised is:

> Access violation at address 0885133F in module 'fmx230.bpl'. Read of
>   address 00000004.

I have adapted the example to make very simple and error continues. I want to get as a result something like this:

[image: composite control]

TwoRectLayout.pas code file is:

```
unit TwoRectLayout;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Classes,System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Math.Vectors,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Styles, FMX.Objects, FMX.Layouts, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs;

type

 TTwoRect = class(TStyledControl)
  private
   FColorTop: TAlphaColor;
   FColorClient: TAlphaColor;
   FRectTop: TRectangle;
   FRectClient: TRectangle;
   procedure SetColorTop(const Value: TAlphaColor);
   procedure SetColorClient(const Value: TAlphaColor);
  protected
   function GetDefaultSize: TSizeF; override;
   function GetStyleObject(const Clone: Boolean): TFmxObject; override;
   procedure ApplyStyle; override;
   procedure FreeStyle; override;
  public
   constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  published
   property Align;
   property Anchors;
   property Cursor;
   property Height;
   property Position;
   property StyleLookup;
   property Visible;
   property Width;
   property Size;
   property ColorTop: TAlphaColor read FColorTop write SetColorTop;
   property ColorClient: TAlphaColor read FColorClient write SetColorClient;
  end;

procedure Register;

implementation

{$R TwoRectLayout.res}

const
  TwoRectstyleName = 'TwoRectstyle';

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('Samples', [TTwoRect]);
end;

procedure TTwoRect.ApplyStyle;
begin
 inherited;

 if not Assigned(FRectTop) then
  FRectTop:= FindStyleResource('RectTopstyle') as TRectangle;

 if Assigned(FRectTop) then
  begin
   FRectTop.Fill.Color:= FColorTop;
  end;

 if not Assigned(FRectClient) then
  FRectClient:= FindStyleResource('RectClientstyle') as TRectangle;

 if Assigned(FRectClient) then
  begin
   FRectClient.Fill.Color:= FColorClient;
  end;

end;

constructor TTwoRect.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
 inherited;
 Width:= 500;
 Height:= 400;

 FColorTop:= TAlphaColors.Blue;
 FColorClient:= TAlphaColors.Gold;
end;

procedure TTwoRect.FreeStyle;
begin
 inherited;
 FRectTop := nil;
 FRectClient := nil;
end;

function TTwoRect.GetDefaultSize: TSizeF;
begin
 Result:= TSizeF.Create(500, 400);
end;

function TTwoRect.GetStyleObject(const Clone: Boolean): TFmxObject;
begin
 if (StyleLookup = '') then
  Result:= TStyleManager.GetStyleResource(TwoRectstyleName)
 else
  Result:= inherited GetStyleObject(Clone);
end;

procedure TTwoRect.SetColorTop(const Value: TAlphaColor);
begin
 if (FColorTop <> Value) then
  begin
   FColorTop:= Value;
   ApplyStyle;
  end;
end;

procedure TTwoRect.SetColorClient(const Value: TAlphaColor);
begin
 if (FColorClient <> Value) then
  begin
   FColorClient:= Value;
   ApplyStyle;
  end;
end;

end.
```

The TwoRectLayout.rc contains this:

```
TwoRectstyle RCDATA  "TwoRectLayout.style"
```

And the definition of style (TwoRectLayout.style) is:

```
  object TLayout
    StyleName = 'TwoRectstyle'
    Position.X = 488.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 281.000000000000000000
    Size.Width = 382.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 283.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    TabOrder = 0
    object TRectangle
      StyleName = 'RectTopstyle'
      Align = Top
      HitTest = False
      Size.Width = 382.000000000000000000
      Size.Height = 32.000000000000000000
      Size.PlatformDefault = False
    end
    object TRectangle
      StyleName = 'RectClientstyle'
      Align = Client
      HitTest = False
      Size.Width = 382.000000000000000000
      Size.Height = 251.000000000000000000
      Size.PlatformDefault = False
    end   
  end
```

As I said the same component works without problem in Delphi XE6, with Delphi 10 Seattle raise this error and I can't see rendered the control at design time. If I compile the program it seems ok. The error details are:

```
[082F133F]{fmx230.bpl  } FMX.Controls.TControl.DoGetUpdateRect (Line 2184, "FMX.Controls.pas" + 44) + $9
[5016FBB9]{rtl230.bpl  } System.Classes.TComponent.Remove (Line 15599, "System.Classes.pas" + 7) + $B
[50060708]{rtl230.bpl  } System.TMonitor.TryEnter (Line 18154, "System.pas" + 10) + $0
[5016FC2F]{rtl230.bpl  } System.Classes.TComponent.Remove (Line 15609, "System.Classes.pas" + 17) + $15
[50060288]{rtl230.bpl  } System.TMonitor.Enter (Line 17847, "System.pas" + 4) + $2
[5016FF1E]{rtl230.bpl  } System.Classes.TComponent.Notification (Line 15712, "System.Classes.pas" + 8) + $1D
[50060288]{rtl230.bpl  } System.TMonitor.Enter (Line 17847, "System.pas" + 4) + $2
[50060467]{rtl230.bpl  } System.TMonitor.Exit (Line 17973, "System.pas" + 2) + $7
[5005F77C]{rtl230.bpl  } System.TObject.Free (Line 16261, "System.pas" + 1) + $4
[082F0570]{fmx230.bpl  } FMX.Controls.TControl.Destroy (Line 1860, "FMX.Controls.pas" + 15) + $19
[5005A19C]{rtl230.bpl  } System.@FreeMem (Line 4650, "System.pas" + 20) + $0
[500619A0]{rtl230.bpl  } System.@UStrClr (Line 24673, "System.pas" + 14) + $0
[50063CEC]{rtl230.bpl  } System.@FinalizeArray (Line 31875, "System.pas" + 80) + $0
[50060708]{rtl230.bpl  } System.TMonitor.TryEnter (Line 18154, "System.pas" + 10) + $0
[50060288]{rtl230.bpl  } System.TMonitor.Enter (Line 17847, "System.pas" + 4) + $2
[50067110]{rtl230.bpl  } System.@IntfClear (Line 36557, "System.pas" + 10) + $0
[50579B15]{rtl230.bpl  } .rtl. (Line 296, "" + 0) + $4AC5
[5006010C]{rtl230.bpl  } System.TMonitor.CheckOwningThread (Line 17765, "System.pas" + 2) + $0
[50060708]{rtl230.bpl  } System.TMonitor.TryEnter (Line 18154, "System.pas" + 10) + $0
[50060288]{rtl230.bpl  } System.TMonitor.Enter (Line 17847, "System.pas" + 4) + $2
[50060467]{rtl230.bpl  } System.TMonitor.Exit (Line 17973, "System.pas" + 2) + $7
[5006010C]{rtl230.bpl  } System.TMonitor.CheckOwningThread (Line 17765, "System.pas" + 2) + $0
[50060416]{rtl230.bpl  } System.TMonitor.Exit (Line 17951, "System.pas" + 1) + $2
[50060467]{rtl230.bpl  } System.TMonitor.Exit (Line 17973, "System.pas" + 2) + $7
[50063CEC]{rtl230.bpl  } System.@FinalizeArray (Line 31875, "System.pas" + 80) + $0
[50063C34]{rtl230.bpl  } System.@FinalizeRecord (Line 31637, "System.pas" + 25) + $0
[5006017C]{rtl230.bpl  } System.TMonitor.Destroy (Line 17787, "System.pas" + 0) + $0
[5005F7FF]{rtl230.bpl  } System.TObject.CleanupInstance (Line 16405, "System.pas" + 24) + $0
[5005A19C]{rtl230.bpl  } System.@FreeMem (Line 4650, "System.pas" + 20) + $0
[5005F5F8]{rtl230.bpl  } System.TObject.FreeInstance (Line 16193, "System.pas" + 2) + $2
[5005FECE]{rtl230.bpl  } System.@ClassDestroy (Line 17542, "System.pas" + 0) + $2
[082F05A2]{fmx230.bpl  } FMX.Controls.TControl.Destroy (Line 1863, "FMX.Controls.pas" + 18) + $9
```

I found the problem, the code used to load the style from a resource in DelphiXE6 was :

> Result:= TFmxObject(TStyleManager.LoadFromResource(HInstance,
>   DecisionTreeCompstyleName, RT_RCDATA))

I changed that code to this, because the previous function isn't in Delphi 10 Seattle:

> Result:= TStyleManager.GetStyleResource(TwoRectstyleName)

but the correct code to use is:

> Result:= TStyleStreaming.LoadFromResource(HInstance,
>   DecisionTreestyleName, RT_RCDATA);

Comment: The Error images really wasn't necessary. You can copy/paste text from both those dialogs, which makes it much easier to read. It's also much friendlier to those using mobile devices or that have visual impairments. Images should only be used when the information cannot be supplied in a different fashion.

Comment: Trying your code I got the same Access violations. I seem to have fixed it by adding RegisterFMXClasses([TTwoRect]); in initialization as per here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19106634/creating-a-firemonkey-component

Comment: Ken White, I changed the post following your suggestion. Thanks Doug, I edit my post with the code that runs now well, it was a problem with the function used to load the style from a resource.