# How can I create an event handler for a non published but public event in delphi?

Tags: delphi, events, tstringgrid, delphi-10.1-berlin

In **RAD Studio 10.1 Berlin** quite a few things has changed from previous version. In FMX there are a few previously published events that has now been changed to only be public.

I have a Multi Platform Project that uses a TStringGrid component and the OnDblClick event. When opening this project in Studio 10.1 I get warned that the Property OnDblClick does not exist.

The question is now how I can use the no longer published event?

(*I must say that It's hard to understand why they haven't set mouse events to Published anymore. As far as I know most regular PCs and OSX machines doesn't have touch. A true Multi Target Project should be able to target these systems without hassle as they did in Studio 10 Seattle*)

Comment: Known bug https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-14683

Comment: Ok, I see. The funny thing though is that the Help file reflects the changed state of these event properties. Therefore I thought it was intentional. Or, maybe it was intentional but not really thought thru??

Comment: The help is created from the source. So this bug is also documented ;o)

Answer (score 3):

In case the event handlers already exist (which I imply by the error message), you can assign these handlers to their events in FormCreate.

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate;
begin
  StringGrid1.OnDblClick := StringGrid1DblClick;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you Uwe! That was exactly what I was looking for. I feel a bit embarrassed for not getting this myself though...

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to make your own component where you extend the `FMX.TStringGrid` to have published event handlers again.

See here how to create a new FMX component: [creating a firemonkey component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19106634/creating-a-firemonkey-component)

Here's the code to re-publish the mouse events.

```
unit MyStringGrid;

interface

uses FMX.Grids;

type
  TMyStringGrid = class(TStringGrid)
  published
    property OnDblClick;
    property OnMouseDown;
    property OnMouseMove; 
    property OnMouseUp;
    property OnMouseWheel;
    property OnMouseEnter;
    property OnMouseLeave;
  end;

procedure Register;

implementation

uses FMX.Types;

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('NewPage', [TMyStringGrid]);
end;

initialization
  RegisterFmxClasses([TMyStringGrid]);
end.
```

Comment: Thank you Johan! This would definitely work but is there any other simpler way to do this? Having to create new components every time a new implementation of a standard component is released by Embarcadero doesn't feel right.

Answer (score 2):

This has been [reported as a bug here](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-14683).

Looking at the source code in Delphi 10.1 berlin the public `OnDblClick` event is actually inherited from `TControl` class.

Similar the `OnDblClick` event is also inherited from `TControl` class with the exception that it is made public, like many other events that are inherited from TControl˙ class.

Any way it seems that guys at Embarcadero have been doing some refactoring by cleaning the parent property redeclarations˙(not sure if this is the right term) like:

```
type
  TParentClass = clas(Tobject)
  public
    property ParentPropery: Integer read GetParentProperty write SetParentProperty;

  TExampleClass = class(TParentClass)
  public
    property ParentPropery;
  end;
```

Redeclaring `ParentProperty` in the above case is not needed as it will be available in all child classes unless you want to change its visibility from `public` to `published` for instance.

If you look at Delphi 10 Seattle source code you see that property `OnDblClick` is redeclared in several `TStringGrid` parent classes being published in `TCustomScrollBox` for the first time.